AWS no longer support for auto launch configurations, so how to use the template while creating eb application on Node.js

How to resolve this error, "Creating Auto Scaling launch configuration failed,

Reason: Resource handler returned message: "The Launch Configuration creation operation is not available in your account.

Use launch templates to create configuration templates for your Auto Scaling groups. (Service: AutoScaling, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 1ccd4aae-5d98-4a25-ae6e-2b427153914e)" (RequestToken: f4e7aa3d-1f68-386d-98e5-a4ecde3cc524, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)"

I want my environment to be configured with green heath.



I'm not sure what we can say except to repeat what the error message tells you to do.  "Use launch templates to create configuration templates for your Auto Scaling groups.".  The documentation is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/launch-templates.html.  There are even tutorials; e.g. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/create-your-first-auto-scaling-group.html
